# Why NSString floatvalue return 0 for "NaN"?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, cgfloat

Why i dont get NaN as result? 0 is wrong. Maybe compiler settings?

```
CGFloat fValue = [@"NaN" floatValue]; // fValue is 0
double ddd = [@"NaN" doubleValue]; // also 0`
```

Edit: Strange, in swift this works and returns nan:

```
let fValue = Float ("NaN")
let ddd = Double ("NaN")
```

Comment: You can just write: `double ddd = NAN;`

Comment: You can write: `double ddd = atof("NaN");`

Comment: Note that your comparison between Objective-C and Swift is comparing completely different cases. In Swift, the `Float` and `Double` structs are handling the conversion from a string. The Objective-C code is asking the `NSString` class for a primitive numeric value. Those are essentially opposite approaches. A better comparison would be if `NSNumber` in Objective-C had an initializer that accepted an `NSString` (it doesn't though). Or if in Swift, `String` had a `floatValue` or `doubleValue` property (it doesn't though). So there simply isn't a fair comparison here.

Answer (score 1):

It's written on the documentation. This is for float value, the same with double value.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412321-floatvalue
>
> > This property doesn’t include whitespace at the beginning of the string. This property is HUGE_VAL or –HUGE_VAL on overflow, 0.0 on underflow. This property is 0.0 if the string doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number.

Comment: What is a valid text representation of NaN? Swift know it, C# know it too.

Comment: In case you are casting "NaN" as a Float, it's valid because Float conforms LosslessStringConvertible protocol which allows you to convert kind of "inf" as infinity or "NaN" as nan. Check on Swift.Math.Floating Foundation.

Comment: OK, i understand that i have to check a string for "NaN" before converting to float.

Comment: And if you want to create a "nan" on Objective-c, just simple like double nan = NAN. There is a macro to represent it.

Answer (score -2):

string "NaN" to float is 0.
0 is right and you is wrong.

Comment: Why? at swift "NaN" is nan and at C# "NaN" is also double.NaN